# Cannot access URL Parameter in Lightning Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, url, isurladdressable

I have an aura component and js as below. I tried accessing URL parameter lightning.force.com/lightning/n/Example?c__param=test but it throws an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'state')]". Am I missing something here.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" description="Handler for valueInit event fired when the component has been initialised"/>
        {!v.pageReference.state.c__hello}
</aura:component>

({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__hello);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small typo in the url which you are using and the component code.

In URL its `c__param` and in component its `c__hello`

Also, URL is needs a change and should be - `lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__Example?c__hello=test`

The general [format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) for Aura Component url is - `instance_url/lightning/cmp/c__{componentname}?c__param=abc`

The JS controller code will look like -

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__param);
}
```

Replace `c__` with `namespace__` if applicable.

**Note** : `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface does not work in communities.